# Stop timer in onDestroy()

Tags: android

Hi guys i want stop my timer in method onDestroy but i don't know what's the best solution...
I have tried timer.purge() in onDestroy but get an error...

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){

     final ToggleButton btnImbarco = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
     final ToggleButton btnAtterraDecolla = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
     final ToggleButton btnRitardo = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);

     if(!btnImbarco.isChecked() && !btnAtterraDecolla.isChecked() && !btnRitardo.isChecked())
         //STOP TIMER HERE
}

public void callAsynchronousTask(final TextView attendere, 
        final ToggleButton btnAtterraDecolla, final ToggleButton btnRitardo, final ToggleButton btnImbarco)
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        FlightTask aTask =  new FlightTask(attendere,btnAtterraDecolla,btnRitardo,btnImbarco);

                        if(btnAtterraDecolla.isChecked())
                            ..........   

                        if(btnRitardo.isChecked())
                            ........... 

                        if(btnImbarco.isChecked())
                            ........

                        aTask.execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, TEMPO_ESECUZIONE_THREAD); //execute in every 50000 ms
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......
```

Can you help me please?
I want only stop the timer when activity is destroyed!
Thank you...

Comment: usually timer.cancel()...but check if timer!=null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually cancel the timer this way:
I have a boolean set to true when i start the timer, then check it in onDestroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopUpdates();
    super.onDestroy();

}
private void stopUpdates() {
    if (isTimerRunning) {
        updateTimer.cancel();
        updateTimer.purge();
        updateTimer = null;
        isTimerRunning = false;
    }
}
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29)